# centering elements using margin { 0 auto }

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to center my "h1" using margin and auto the left and right sides, later in my code I have a table for which I did the same thing and it did work.

my CSS code is:

```
h1 {
    margin: auto 0;
}

td {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
table {
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

later its just classes.. help?

Comment: The heading is 100% wide so it is centered.

Comment: Add `display:table;` to your `h1`

Answer (score 1):

Your h1 should have the property `margin: 0 auto;` not `auto 0`.

It also needs to have a fixed width in order for that to work.

You should use `h1 { text-align: center; }` to center the text in the h1 in most situations.